# After installing Windows XP Service Pack 3 - Generic Host Process For Win32 Services problem starts

Tags: windows-xp, sp3

After installing Service Pack 3 I am getting this error "Generic Host Process For Win32 Services Encountered A Problem and needs to close.

When this message pops my computer just stuck and I can not even restart it normally.

The only fix of this problem is to un-install service pack 3 and run fix from Microsoft which is available for Service Pack 2.

Any help to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of Service Pack installation issues can be avoided by following the installation instructions.  They're long, but full of surprises.  For instance, they strongly recommend stopping all non-Microsoft services before running the SP installer.  I've had problems similar to this one that were resolved by paying attention to the SP readme.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall SP3, reboot and configure XP for a Clean Boot state, install SP3 in the clean boot state, reboot and undo the clean boot settings, reboot once again.

See steps 1-3 in method 2

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310353

Sometimes this svchost error is due to malware on the system, uninstall SP3, reboot, then follow these instructions to remove nasties, then install SP3 in a Clean Boot State as suggested.

.

Follow the order given below to properly disinfect your PC

1.) Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.